# Error when creating a decorator for ui.bootstrap.modal - modalWindow

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm trying to decorate the `modalWindow` directive from the ui.bootstrap.modal module.

Here is my code:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.modal').config(function($provide){

    $provide.decorator('modalWindowDirective', ['$delegate', '$timeout', function ($delegate, $timeout) {

        var directive = $delegate[0];


        directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.windowClass = attrs.windowClass || '';

            /* this is what I added*/
            element.css('width', 'auto');
            element.css({ 'left': '50%', 'margin-left': -(element.width() / 2) + 'px' });
            /*----------*/

            //trigger CSS transitions
            $timeout(function () {
                scope.animate = true;
            });
        };
    }]);
});
```

When I do that, I got the error:

`Raven: Exception  TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

Even if I remove the content of the decorator like that:

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.modal').config(function($provide){

    $provide.decorator('modalWindowDirective', ['$delegate', '$timeout', function ($delegate, $timeout) {


    }]);
});
```

I keep getting this error

Here is a plnkr: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/x4p1MvZS7O4uEtB0qQC6

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/x4p1MvZS7O4uEtB0qQC6?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the `$delegate` when decorating.

Also, you need to decorate the `compile` function (and within, decorate the `link` function), and not `directive.link` function directly.

<kbd>[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/ploxCkpne0DrRYkIoDqA?p=preview)</kbd>

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.modal').config(function($provide){

  $provide.decorator('modalWindowDirective', ['$delegate', '$timeout', function ($delegate, $timeout) {

    var directive = $delegate[0];

    directive.compile = function(){
      return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.windowClass = attrs.windowClass || '';
        console.log('TEST LOG');

        element.css('width', 'auto');
        element.css({ 'left': '50%', 'margin-left': -(element.width() / 2) + 'px' });

        //trigger CSS transitions
        $timeout(function () {
          scope.animate = true;
        });

      };
    }

    return $delegate;
  }]);
});
```

<sub>Note: You need full jQuery in order to user `element.width()`.</sub>